# I need suggestions on how to track and record power cuts in my home using RaspberryPi or ESP32 or ESP8266

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi4

I need to record the date and time when the power is off and monitor/record once the power is back. I also want to calculate the duration of each power outage in minutes and track how many times it happens in a day.

**Here are a couple of points to address:**

Is there a way to detect if my Raspberry Pi is running on the inverter instead of the main power supply?
Do I need multiple devices, one connected to the main power supply and the other connected to the inverter?
Additionally, please let me know if there are any libraries available that can help with this task. I'm a beginner in electronics and appreciate any guidance.

**Note:** I have a power backup (inverter) for specific sockets where I can connect either a Raspberry Pi 4, ESP32, or ESP8266 to monitor power status.

Comment: Can you talk to the inverter? (Does it have some kind of communication interface?)

Comment: @PMF No. It is a normal inverter (power backup).

Comment: Then you need a voltage sensor you can attach to the input power line(s). I guess there are out-of-the-box sensors for that, or you could make your own. I would not recommend the later, as messing around with AC power is dangerous without adequate qualification.

Answer (score 0):

A really quick and dirty hack that you can do whilst you figure out more advanced approach with voltage sensors. It's just with two ESP8266 and don't even need to involve the PI or even bother the inverter:

1. Set a simple web server on one ESP and have it run it's own hotspot (Soft AP mode) and regulate the DNS itself (basically become the http://localhost)
   Plug it into a power bank that is constantly charging so it will always be on.

You should also maybe include a RTC for that ESP so it can maintain an accurate clock

2. On the second ESP make it run from a wall outlet and set it to connect to the ESP1 WiFi SSID and send http requests on regular interval, dunno, maybe 10 seconds.

First time it wakes up it can send a simple GET that will mean it's awake i.e. http://localhost/hello

After that it will keep sending a heartbeat i.e. http://localhost/ping

3. ESP1 can save every time it receives a request from ESP2 with a time from the RTC to some text file using LittleFS

So, when power goes down ESP 2 goes down and the last thing recorded on ESP 1 will be the last heartbeat ping with the time. Effectively you will know when the power has gone down within 10 seconds of the last heartbeat

When power comes back, ESP 2 get electrical juice and wakes up, connects to the ESP 1 WiFi, sends it's first "hello" and ESP2 records that

You can then simply connect your phone to ESP 1 wifi, use the browser go to something like http://localhost/log and it can read and return everything it has recorded

You could do all that over your home WiFi but that would involve reconnects, mDNS etc

Silly idea but dead simple, quick and cheap to make.

This is in essence the same logic that you use with things like WebSockets and server/client connections, it's all about heartbeats, pings & pongs, nothing more sophisticated but the world runs on it :-)